# How can I create an event in a Java class in Android and listen to it in my MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, events

So I want to perform some task in a background thread and when it is completed, I want to notify MainActivity to update UI depending on the result.

Should I RxJava for reactive purposes? Or something like broadcast receiver in the Activity?

Comment: AsyncTask with a callback to the main activity in the onPostExecute method?

Comment: @Amin AsyncTask is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).